# How to remove margin between RecyclerView items

Tags: android

I am trying to make a screen as shown in the picture, as you can see there is no spacing between items in the RecyclerView.

**Desired Image:**

[image: desired picture]

So far my **item_layout** for each of the item in recycler view is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colorBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/colorNameBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="asd"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16dp"

            >

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

my ItemDecoration in **ColorShadesActivity** is given below:

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

            private int spanCount; //3
            private int spacing; //0
            private boolean includeEdge; //false

            public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
                this.spanCount = spanCount;
                this.spacing = spacing;
                this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
            }

            @Override
            public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
                int column = position % spanCount; // item column

                if (includeEdge) {
                    outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                    outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                    if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                        outRect.top = spacing;
                    }
                    outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
                } else {
                    outRect.left = spacing; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                    outRect.right = spacing; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                    if (position >= spanCount) {
                        outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

But the **result** I am getting is:
[image]

Comment: you have given fixed width to your card view . Try removing that fixed width . As span count is give , it will take width on its own .

Comment: find the device width and then set views width as 1/3 of it.

Comment: @MiniChip That worked

Answer (score 0):

To show GridLayout using RecyclerView You need to make only few steps:

1. tell RecyclerView that You want to show the elements in GridLayout
2. declare how many columns You would like to use in GridLayout
3. set the same height for every element in case You would like to show all elements in equal rows

Here is a working sample code in simplified way to achieve that what You want. I am dynamically change item's height but You can use xml layout for that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Random random;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewGroup, false);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = inflate.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity * 56);
                inflate.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                int randomColor = random.nextInt(Colors.COLORS.length);
                inflate.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Colors.COLORS[randomColor]));

                return new RecyclerViewViewHolder(inflate);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                ((TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(Cheeses.CHEESES[i]);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return Cheeses.CHEESES.length;
            }
        });
    }

    private class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: gridlayout recyclerview android]

[Source on Github](https://github.com/SmithWhiteFirst/RecyclerView-Basics)